# How to get some notification when connection removed from pool, C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application i am trying to get some notification, when connection is removed from pool, due to many different cases, that can be network failure, sleep mode..etc.

**ConnectionString = MinPoolSize = 1;**

My requirements are as following

1. I want to recheck active connections, so that limited users only can access system.
2. Get notification in application, if connection is removed from pool by `sql`.

It can also be okay, I f i can get some general event when connection gets removed from pool.

Please share your idea to handle above situations.

Best Regards,
Samir

Comment: the fact you want to do this is very unusual....

Comment: This is not how ADO.net connection pooling works. Connections are removed from the pool when they time out or are detected as severed. Pools promote better performance and in general, no lower level interface is necessary nor are either of your 2 requirements applicable to ado.net connection pools. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how ADO.net connection pooling works. Connections are removed from the pool when they time out or are detected as severed. Pools promote better performance and in general, no lower level interface is necessary nor are either of your 2 requirements applicable to ado.net connection pools.

See [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.